# Modify URLs generated by CKEditor Link for specific node type

Tags: 7, navigation, wysiwyg

How do you alter the URL generated by CKEditor Link, for a specific content type.

For example I have *book_section* content type. If a content editor links to a node with type of *book_section* I want to step in and link to a fragment/anchor within the parent node instead. The convention of my anchor ids are `<a id="/node-alias" />`

As per [documentation provided by the CKEditor Link module author](https://www.drupal.org/node/1107954) I've used `hook_ckeditor_link_types` and `hook_ckeditor_link_TYPE_url` in a custom module to make the following modifications.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_ckeditor_link_types
 */
function ajf_ckeditor_link_types() {
    return array('book_section');
}

/**
 * Implements hook_ckeditor_link_TYPE_url
 *
 */
function ajf_ckeditor_link_book_section_url( $path, $langcode ) {
    if (!preg_match('`^node/(\d+)$`', $path, $matches)) {
        return;
    }

    $nid = $matches[1];
    $node = node_load( $nid );

    if ( 'book_section' != $node->type ) {
        return;
    }

    $parent = menu_link_load( $node->book['plid'] );
    $options = array( 'fragment' => '/'. $node->path['alias'] );
    $url = ckeditor_link_url( $parent['link_path'], $langcode, $options );
    return $url;
}
```

When viewing a page with links to *book_section* nodes I'm getting an empty response from the server. I'm thinking the repeated `node_load` calls is exceeding the servers resources.

Appreciate advice you may have.